# How to properly handle socket accept returning "Too many open files"

Tags: c, sockets

I have a listening socket on a tcp port. The process itself is using `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&...);` to configure how many sockets are allowed for the process.

For tests RLIMIT_NOFILE is set to 20 and of course for production it will be set to a sanely bigger number. 20 is good for easily reaching the limit in a test environment.

The server itself has no issues like descriptor leak or similar, but trying to solve the problem by increasing RLIMIT_NOFILE obviously cannot do, because in real life there is no guarantee the the limit will not be reached, no matter how high it is set.

The problem is that after reaching the limit `accept` returns `Too many open files` and unless a file or socket is closed the event loop starts spinning without delay, eating 100% of one core. Even if the client closes the connection (e.g. because of timeout), the server will loop until a file descriptor is available to process and close the already dead incoming connection. **EDIT:** On the other hand the client stalls and there is no good way to know that the server is overloaded.

My question: is there some standard way to handle this situation by closing the incoming connection after `accept` returns `Too many open files`.

Several dirty approaches come to mind:

- To close and reopen the listening socket with the hope that all pending connections will be closed (this is quite dirty because in threaded server some other thread may get the freed file descriptor)
- To track open file descriptor count (this cannot be properly done with external libraries that will have some untracked file descriptors)
- To check if file descriptor number is near the limit and start closing incoming connections before the situation happens (this is rather implementation specific and while it will work on Linux, there is no guarantee that other OS will handle file descriptors in the same way)

**EDIT:** One more dirty and ugly approach:

To keep one spare fd (e.g. `dup(STDIN_FILENO)` or `open("/dev/null",...)`) that will be used in case `accept` fails. The sequence will be:

```
... accept failed
// stop threads
close(sparefd);
newconnection = accept(...);
close(newconnection);
sparefd = open("/dev/null",...);
// release threads
```

The main drawback with this approach is thread synchronization to prevent other threads to get the just freed spare fd.

Comment: External libraries that unexpectedly keep file descriptors open are pretty rare. `syslog` opens a socket to `syslogd`, DB access libraries have an FD for each database session. I expect that a buffer of 10 FDs would be more than enough in any sane application.

Comment: True, but not always - libtorrent comes to mind as a counter example ;)

Comment: I did say rare. You presumably know what kinds of libraries you're using in your application, so you should be able to estimate what their likely use of fds will be, unless what you're trying to design is a general purpose library.

Comment: Exactly this is the question - how to solve the general case. Your guess is right - its a library

Comment: There may simply be no good solution.

Comment: If you get a "too many open files" error then don't keep retrying? That would fix the fact that you get 100% CPU usage from continuously retrying.

Comment: If you can't control the external library's rampant use of fd's, confine it to its own process(es). Maybe you can have the main server process do nothing except listen for connections and then pass the accepted fd to one of a set number of worker processes, and they can deal with any badly-behaved libraries.

Comment: I would go with number 3 if I were handling HTTP connections (when the `fd` is close to the limit, send a `503` error and close), but it's somewhat protocol specific and there isn't really a general standard solution. Not accepting new connections and using edge triggered events come to mind when reaching the end of the resource pool.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your question, because it seems like many answerers have not.  You want to make sure your code is well-behaved if it runs out of fds.  To test this, you are *temporarily*, *artificially* lowering the fd limit using `setrlimit`.  And it's good you performed this test, because you discovered a surprise: your code in fact behaves badly when it runs out of fds, and you'd like to understand why, and figure out how to fix it.  Your production code will *not* call `setrlimit`, but if it ever runs out of fds, you'd like it to behave gracefully.

Comment: @SteveSummit exactly. Looks like Barmar was right that there is no good solution. Only one ugly (but generic) way comes to my mind - to keep one fd (e.g. of /dev/null) and after accept returns the error, close it, accept and close the incoming connection, then reopen /dev/null. That will also require stopping all other threads...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `setrlimit` to control how many simultaneous connections your process can handle.  Your tiny little bit of socket code is saying to the whole rest of the application, "I only want to have N connections open at a time, and this is the only way I know how to do it, so... nothing else in the process can have any files!".  What would happen if everybody did that?

The proper way to do what you want is easy -- keep track of how many connections you have open, and just don't call `accept` until you can handle another one.

Comment: rlimit is already there, no matter if I change it or not. Tracking just the socket connections is not a solution because there may be other file descriptors open. Of course I can use edge triggered events, but removing listening socket from event handling and checking by open("/dev/null",...) if I can accept another one looks ugly too.

Comment: @bbonev If there may be other file descriptors open, using rlimit as a control on the number of socket connections **cannot possibly work.** So, you shouldn't use it. Whenever you get this error, you need to close some FDs, and if you're engaged in a loop than continually generates new FDs, such as this accept loop, you need to stop it until you have freed some existing FDs. As this answer says.

Comment: I *think* this answer completely misunderstands the question.  The OP is not calling `setrlimit` to "control how many simultaneous connections the process can handle".  The OP is calling `setrlimit` to test the code's behavior if it whould ever run out of fds, and has discovered that the behavior is poor, and is wondering why.

Comment: @SteveSummit, the limit on file handles is generally quite high, and running out of file handles is something that should not happen in normal operation, like running out of memory.  Usually an abortive shutdown is a reasonable way to handle a condition like that.  You *could* just decrease the number of allowed connections, but then you'd be left with no available handles, and that is just not a safe/normal state for a process to be in.

Comment: @bbonev I mean you just set the limit high enough that you don't have to worry about it, *decide* how many simultaneous connections you want to allow, and then don't accept more than that.  See previous comment if you   really need to adapt to an externally applied limit.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Understand your points, but you did say "usually" and "reasonable".  It's possible the OP is operating under requirements of high reliability, and can't be so cavalier about the possibility of just running out and aborting.

Comment: Closing existing fds is not an option. Increasing the limits does not mean that the new one will not be reached. Removing the listening socket from the event loop is not an option too, because new clients will get stalled and the only way to know that something bad is happening is by timeout. Tracking all open fds is not trivial in a portable and generic way. As @SteveSummit said, all there measures are known and listed in the question; I am looking for a way to reject incoming connections after the limit is reached and recover by itself after fds are freed.

Answer (score 1):

notice that multiplexing syscalls such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) can work (so wait without busy spin looping) on `accept`-ing sockets (and on connected sockets also, or any other kind of stream file descriptor).

So just have your event loop handle them (probably with other readable & writable file descriptors). And don't call [accept(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) when you don't want to.

Comment: Well, he wants to. Perhaps a little too much (like an inexperienced lover, he approaches too fast).

Comment: after poll returns an event on the listening socket and in case there are no free fds, accept will fail, client will stall and poll will continue to report read event on the listening socket without delay...

Comment: @bbonev You could poll your other file descriptors (where data is transmitted to and from clients) together with the accept fd. The ones which do work would be processed first, if a certain number of open fds is exceeded, before the accept is performed again. That way you prevent resource exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your code is in a library. The library encounters a resource limit event. I would distinguish, generally, between events which are catastrophic (memory exhaustion, can't open listening socket) and those which are probably temporary. Catastrophic events are hard to handle: without memory, even logging or an orderly shutdown may be impossible.

Too many open files, by contrast, is a condition which is probably temporary, not least because we are the resource hog. Temporary error conditions are luckily trivial to handle: By waiting. This is what you don't do: You should wait for a spell after `accept` returns "Too many open files", before you call `accept` again. That will solve the 100% CPU load problem. (I assume that our server performs some work on each connection which is at some point finished, so that the file descriptors of the client connections which our library holds are eventually closed.)

There remains the problem that the library cannot know the requirements of the user code. (How long should the pause between `accept`s be?<sup>1</sup> Is it at all acceptable (sic) to let connection requests wait at all? Do we give up at some point?) **It is imperative to report errors back to the user code, so that the user code has a chance to see and fix the error.**

If the user code gets the file descriptor back, that's easy: Return `accept`'s error code (and make sure to document that possibility). So I assume that the user code never sees gritty details like file descriptors but instead gets some data, for example. It may even be that the library performs just side effects, possibly concurrently, so that user code never sees any return value which would be usable to communicate errors. Then the library must provide some other way to signal the error condition to the user code. This may impose restrictions on how the user code can use the library: Perhaps before or after certain function calls, or simply periodically,  an error status must be actively checked.

---

<sup>1</sup>By the way, it is not clear to me, even after reading the `accept` man page, whether the client's `connect` fails (because the connection request has been de-queued on the server side but cannot be handled), or whether the request simply stays in the queue so that the client is oblivious of the server's problems, apart from a delay.

Comment: Testing on Linux, the result is that the kernel does not know/check that the process is out of fds; as a result the client connects and stalls and the listening socket fd has pending read event. Even if the problematic client waits for timeout and is gone, the event on listening socket is still pending. Until now I do not see a better approach than #4 in the question...

Comment: You mean it is not possible to `accept` that pending connection later (in the same process) when  another fd has  been freed so that the resource "fd" has become available again??

Comment: Yes, there is no "selectable" event that gives there is a free fd. Busy spinning between epoll_wait and accept does not make much sense on the other hand removing the listening socket from epoll events and checking if there is a free fd after epoll_wait timeouts will solve the cpu problem for the server but will leave not accepted clients stalled. I have asked the question looking for a clean and portable way, alas there seems to be none.